# How can I convert mysql to laravel eloquent left join?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Mysql query like this :

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.TotalMeal, c.TotalCollection
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, SUM( breakfast + dinner + lanch ) AS TotalMeal
    FROM meals
    GROUP BY user_id) b ON a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, SUM( amount ) AS TotalCollection
    FROM collections
    GROUP BY user_id) c ON a.id = c.user_id
LIMIT 0, 30
```

I want to convert it to Laravel eloquent, but I'm confused. I have Three tables. eg - users( id, name,email ..), meals( user_id, breakfast,lanch,dinner) and collections(user_id, amount) .

Comment: You should use relations if you don't want to use joins. If you need joins, then this is the correct way.[enter link description here](http://%20http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

There is a little hack that uses `withCount()` to select sums of related tables which can be used in your scenario:

```
User::query()
    ->select([
        'id',
        'name',
    ])
    ->withCount([
        'meals as total_meals' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(breakfast + dinner + lunch)'));
        },
        'collections as total_collections' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount)'));
        },
    ])
    ->get();
```

In this query, `withCount` will perform the joins for you.